# CollapsingToolbarLayout not collapsing while scrolling

Tags: java, android, xml, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am using CollapsingToolbarLayout and a viewpager. Viewpager consists of RecyclerView. But when recycler view is scrolled the toolbar is not collapsing.

**activity_home.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/htab_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/header"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/htab_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:gravity="top"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:titleMarginTop="13dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

**fragment_one.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

**HomeActivity.java**

```
import javax.swing.text.View;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.htab_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null)
                        .show();
            }
        });

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        final CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(
                R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("News");
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        String[] categories = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories);
        for (String category : categories) {
            OneFragment fragment = new OneFragment();
            adapter.addFragment(fragment, category);
        }
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: where you are adding fragment?? in viewPager??

Answer (score 1):

just use `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` in Toolbar
and good practice if you used Coordinator layout also.

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       android:id="@+id/htab_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:gravity="top"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleMarginTop="13dp" 
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: @ArunN did you added coordinator layout??

Comment: yes activity_home code is enclosed in 

`<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/htab_maincontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout >`

Comment: okk then once refer this example.. http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/collapsing-toolbar-with-tabs-android-example/

Comment: @ArunN  did you done?? i have a doubt in your question. you gave the activity_home xml file but you used in HomeActivity activity_main class?? are you inflating right layout??

Answer (score 0):

change your layout to this

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.sandeeppatel.appbarandtablayout.MainActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="snap"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Let me know in case of any issue

Comment: @Arun N Have you test this layout you need to keep appbar inside the cordinator layout check given xml